# REGEX Help required with a optional values

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have a regex to parse the below string:

```
{ "<div class="highlighttitle2">UNSPSC 43211701</div>" }
```

The whole string is option. The output I need is

UNSPC: 43211701

Please help.

I have tried..

```
.*?((?(?=ul).*?(?(?=div)|.*?\bUNSPSC\b.*?(?'UNSPSC'[^<]*)</div>)|.*?(?(?=div).*?\bUNSPSC\b.*?(?'UNSPSC'[^<]*)</div>|))|).*?((?(?=ul).*?(?(?=div)|.*?\bUNSPSC\b.*?(?'UNSPSC'[^<]*)</div>)|.*?(?(?=div).*?\bUNSPSC\b.*?(?'UNSPSC'[^<]*)</div>|))|)
```

Comment: What do you mean with **The whole string is option.**. Have you already tried any `regex`. Which language?

Comment: the string is part of the a big test string. I have tried couple of them like <.*?<.*?((?(?=ul).*?(?(?=div)|.*?\bUNSPSC\b.*?(?'UNSPSC'[^<]*)</div>)|.*?(?(?=div).*?\bUNSPSC\b.*?(?'UNSPSC'[^<]*)</div>|))|).*?((?(?=ul).*?(?(?=div)|.*?\bUNSPSC\b.*?(?'UNSPSC'[^<]*)</div>)|.*?(?(?=div).*?\bUNSPSC\b.*?(?'UNSPSC'[^<]*)</div>|))

Comment: JavaScript is the language.

Comment: Okay, best is to add both (your actual regex and the language) into the text of the question. Also, all `JavaScript` to the tags.

Comment: Obligatory: You should not be using regex to parse HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I'm not sure your regex needs to be that complicated, but it's hard to tell for sure without knowing the possible values your are trying to extract. Is UNSPSC always going to be constant? Is 43211701 always going to be the same length? Always numbers? Any extra information would be helpful.

Comment: Which tags do you want to extract the text of?

Comment: Please verify that you need the colon (:) if your output, as that is not part of your test string. Also, please provide your entire test string, or at least enough to see what pitfalls we need to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the string is always going to start with `UNSPC` and it is followed by numbers with no whitespaces, then your regex could be

```
(UNSPC \d*)
```

And your result, `UNSPC 43211701`, will be in the first capture group.

Answer (score 1):

This will give back as few matches as possible (probably what you're looking for)

```
(UNSPSC\s\d+?(?=<))
```

It won't care how many digits there are but will give you only one match instead of a match per digit.